# How do you get into Hogwarts if you are muggle-born?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

If  you're muggle-born how do you get your acceptance letter to Hogwarts if it has 'muggle repelling charms' on it?

How, for example did Hermione Granger get her letter and how did she reply to it?

Comment: Muggle born, and Muggles are different. Hermione is a which even if her parents are not. Not quite sure what they do about parents evening though.

Comment: first year: by boat

Answer (score 38):

JKR answered this in an [interview in 2004](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2004/0304-wbd.htm):

> **How are Muggle parents convinced to let their kids go to Hogwarts, a strange place they never heard of before; and wouldn’t they think it was a practical joke?**
>
> In the case of Muggle parents, special messengers are sent to explain everything to them. But don’t forget that they will have noticed that there’s something strange about their child for the previous ten years, so it won’t come as a complete bolt from the blue.

We also see this in one of Snape’s memories, where he explains the Hogwarts letter to Lily:

> **Snape:** ...we'll get the letter, you and me.
>
> **Lily:** Really?
>
> **Snape:** Definitely.
>
> **Lily:** And will it really come by owl?
>
> **Snape:** Normally. But you're Muggle-born, so someone from the school will have to come and explain to your parents.

Two other instances about admissions letters are somewhat interesting here:

- Harry is a half-blood, but is being raised by two Muggles who reject the idea of magic (even if they begrudgingly accept its existence). His first letter is sent through the Muggle post, and when it’s clear that his letters aren’t being received, Hagrid gets dispatched to straighten things out.
- Lupin is also a half-blood, and grew up with both of his parents, but he had his werewolf bite before he got his Hogwarts letter. Both of them assumed he wouldn’t be able to attend, but Dumbledore himself paid them a visit to assure them that he could attend.

Comment: and Tom Riddle had Dumbledore deliver his letter

Comment: Aside: Is Harry Half-Blood ? - Lily is half blood, but a witch, James is pureblood. Doesn't that make Harry pureblood (or at least 3/4 blood ?)

Comment: Harry's a half-blood, lily's muggle born and james is pure blood. I wish I was pure blood, then I could be certain I am going to Hogwarts. I live every day wishing it.

Comment: @PatDobson: I consider Harry as a half-blood because Lily was Muggle-born and James was pure-blood, but it doesn’t have much bearing on the answer. // Better; see this answer from JKR: http://web.archive.org/web/20110607111410/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=58

Answer (score -1):

Well, Hermione wouldn't have to reply, because the messenger will come to her to await her answer. And the letter itself doesn't have muggle repelling charms on it.

Comment: Do you have canon confirmation for both of these facts?

Comment: The letter can't have muggle-repelling charms on it, because the Dursleys take the letters from Harry--something they could not do in the presence of such a charm. (And it would make literally no sense to put muggle repelling charms on them if you are sending them to muggles or people who live with muggles, like half-bloods.)

That Muggle-born witches and wizards receive a personal invitation from a messenger is amply supported by Alex's answer.

Answer (score -1):

A person is sent to explain everything and give a child who is 11 and muggle born a letter

Comment: Harry Potter was not Muggle born, he was Muggle raised.