# How did Hermione get all her books for first year?

Tags: harry-potter

I guess this question applies to all "muggle-born" witches/wizards...

How do they get their books? Does the letter contain additional information on how to travel to Diagon Alley? Does an escort come and take them, similar to how Hagrid helped Harry?

In the second book we see that her parents are there with her, but did they go the first year? If that's the case, how would Hermione and her family ever know how to get in?

Comment: Somewhere in the books it's stated that for muggle-borns, a representative from the school goes and explains everything in person, which presumably includes telling them how to get to Diagon Alley (as Dumbledore did for Tom Riddle).

Comment: @Richard - Neither one is "technically" a dupe, since this talks about Hogwarts, but here is canon answer: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47724/how-do-you-get-into-hogwarts-if-you-are-muggle-born

Comment: @Kevin - I believe it's in HP:DH, where they are going through Snape's memories of Lily. It's also referenced in the answer I linked.

Comment: Thanks guys! That does clear it up, then! I was re-reading the series and that question just popped up ; if I had only waited to get all the way to Deathly Hallows to get my question answered. :D