# Does Hagrid visit every student that doesn't respond to their letters?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that Hagrid visits Harry to pick him up when he didn't respond to his Hogwarts letter.

Is this general school policy, or is Harry a special case?

Comment: Related: ["How do you get into Hogwarts if you are Muggle-born?"](http://www.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47724/how-do-you-get-into-hogwarts-if-you-are-muggle-born).

Answer (score 10):

Usually when muggle-born kids get their Hogwarts letter someone from Hogwarts usually comes and explains everything but I don't think Hagrid is the one who goes, maybe its one of the senior teachers.

> “And will it really come by owl?” Lily whispered.
>
> “Normally,” said Snape. “**But you’re Muggle-born, so someone from the school will have to come and explain to your parents.**”
>
> *Deathly Hallows, Chapter 33: The Prince's Tale*

Harry of course is a special case, with his history and everything. Dumbledore suspected Dusrleys to give trouble and hence he sends Hagrid to personally explain things to Harry. Dumbledore trusted Hagrid to do this seeing as he was also the one who had been sent to pick up baby Harry from Godrics Hollow.

> "Sorry?" barked Hagrid, turning to stare at the Dursleys, who shrank back into the shadows. "It's them as should be sorry! **I knew yeh weren't gettin' yer letters** but I never thought yeh wouldn't even know abou' Hogwarts, fer cryin' out loud! Did yeh never wonder where yet parents learned it all?"
>
> "I never expected this," he said, in a low, worried voice. "I had no idea, when **Dumbledore told me there might be trouble gettin' hold of yeh**, how much yeh didn't know. Ah, Harry, I don' know if I'm the right person ter tell yeh -- but someone's gotta -- yeh can't go off ter Hogwarts not knowin'."
>
> *Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 4: The keeper of the keys*

P.S: Edit suggested by @Vishvesh

Dumbledore himself went to recruit Tom Riddle since he didn't have parents and someone needed to explain things to head of the orphanage.

Comment: Even Dumbledore had gone to recruit a wizard! You could add that to your answer.

Comment: @Vishvesh I don't think i remember this. Who did  Dumbledore go to recruit?

Comment: He recruited young Tom Riddle.

Comment: @Vishvesh Damnnnn, I feel so dumb,

Comment: Important thing is that you are contributing. More answers you post better you will get. Keep posting buddy!