# What magic would trigger the Trace to alert the Ministry?

Tags: harry-potter

[This answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/18989/5638) quotes Mad-Eye as saying,

> If you, or anyone around you, casts a spell to get you out of here, Thicknesse is going to know about it.

This seems to suggest that non-spell magic would not notify the Ministry.  Does that mean stuff like Potions or Charms are acceptable?

Comment: Charms are spells. Dobby probably used Wingardium Leviosar around Harry, which was picked up the Underage magic department. Wingardium Leviosar was taught in Charm

Comment: Related: [Can a Muggle become a potions maker?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11846/98028) (potions involve wand usage, apparently) and [How is “The Trace” applied in Harry Potter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10459/98028)

Comment: @Raptor My bad, I thought it would be an item with a spell on it, like the invisibility cloak or maybe a chocolate frog.

Comment: Considering this seems to have happened in Deathly Hallows and they were probably using Brooms and Sirius' motorcycle, none of the above were detected by the ministry.

Comment: Your proposed suggestion might be correct, but it is really a logical fallacy in general. Just because A causes B, that doesn't necessarily mean that C doesn't cause B. Although I do agree here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. Non-spell magic would not alert the Ministry. This is essentially explicitly stated by Moody a few lines later (my emphasis):

> "We're going to use the only means of transport left to us, the only
>   ones the Trace can't detect, **because we don't need to cast spells to
>   use them**: brooms, thestrals, and Hagrid's motorbike."

Using potions would (generally speaking) not involve casting any spells, and indeed on this very occasion they used the Polyjuice Potion. Actually creating potions might involve the casting of spells at some point, and if such spells were cast the Ministry would indeed be alerted (but that was not the case in this scene). Charms would involve casting spells so they would be detected by the Ministry.