# How to identify a magic user?

Tags: harry-potter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the Hogwarts Headmaster know whom to invite to school?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10433/how-does-the-hogwarts-headmaster-know-whom-to-invite-to-school)

In Harry Potter universe, not everyone can do magic. Only magic users can do that. But, how to identify a newly borned child that he/she is magic user or not?

In Star Wars universe, we've midi-chlorians existence using which we can identify someone as force user. I was looking for similar things without any luck.

How does Wizard and Witchcraft universities send invitation letters to 11 year kids?

Comment: @Izkata - duh. I should have remembered - I answered that one with the same source :(

Comment: I've also voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special quill that Minerva McGonagall had that wrote the names of all magic users to invite upon birth.

> In Hogwarts there's a magical quill which detects the birth of a magical child, and writes his or her name down in a large parchment book. Every year Professor McGonagall checks the book, and sends owls to the people who are turning 11. (*JKR chat, Scholastic.com, 2/3/2000*)

Something similar must also exist at the Ministry to start monitoring for Underage Magic violations, but there's no canon mention of the details.

Comment: Full transcript of interview appears here: http://www.scholastic.com/teachers/article/interview-j-k-rowling