# How do wizards/witches identify each other as such?

Tags: harry-potter

I was reading [How does the Hogwarts Headmaster know whom to invite to school?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10433/how-does-the-hogwarts-headmaster-know-whom-to-invite-to-school?s=1|1.8235) and it got me thinking, how can wizards and witches tell if a person they are dealing with is a muggle?

Comment: If they do magic, they're probably not a muggle.

Comment: Wand ownership.

Comment: The Force is strong in this one!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is "they can't", absent visual cues (dress code, having a wand, living in Wizarding area etc...).

- If you recall, Neville's family didn't even think he was a wizard till he got accidentally dropped out the window and bounced.
- Aside from Harry and probably some teachers, nobody knows that Filch is a squib.

Now, considering that there's a special quill that records every wizard being born (for Hogwarts), that's plainly NOT a magically impossible task. But somehow, nobody ever displays any ability to clearly do so aside from said Quill as well as a Sorting Hat (who is telepathic).

Comment: I always though Neville's great uncle (or some such) threw him out the window.

Comment: @DaveJohnson - he didn't "throw". He was distracted. `"Great Uncle Algie came round for dinner, and he was hanging me out of an upstairs window by the ankles when my Great Auntie Enid offered him a meringue and he accidentally let go."`